# How do I stop iCal from automatically adding alarms to new events?

Tags: ical

I am running iCal on Snow Leopard and, whenever I add a new all day event, two alarms are automatically added, but only after I save the event. There are no alarms present when I create the event; they only appear afterwards.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 4):

There is an option in the preferences "General" tab, called "Add a default alarm to all new events and invitations". Maybe that's activated?

Answer (score 2):

Check the settings of the calendar service you are syncing with.  If you are adding an event to a Google calendar it will apply the notification settings of that calendar. You can manage the notification preferences within Google Calendar.